# Provide dependency among modules in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am using to Terraform modules in a `main.tf` file as follows:

```
module "jenkins" {
  install_jenkins = "${var.install_jenkins}"
  jenkins_plugins_list = "${var.jenkins_plugins_list}"
}

module "kube" {
  source        = "../../../../modules-terraform/kube_internal"
  cluster_count = "${var.gke_cluster_create}"

}
```

I want the `jenkins` module to execute **after** the `kube` module.

Is there a way to do so in Terraform `0.11.14` (or even a workaround)?

I couldn't find anything relevant in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/modules.html).

Comment: Module level `depends_on` does not exist in Terraform 0.11. Easiest way to work with this would be two distinct configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hacky workaround available in 0.11.14 is to have the jenkins module create a resource based on output of the kube module, and have the other resources depend on that resource, e.g.

```
variable "cluster_id" {
  descripion = "passed by kube module to create dependency on kube module"
}

resource "null_resource" "cluster" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    # Create dependency on kubernetes cluster by calling variable
    command = "echo ${var.cluster_id}"
  }
}

resource "some_other_resource" "other" {
  depends_on = ["null_resource.cluster"]
}
```